# How to change status bar color?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I am using an image as the background for my `ViewController's`. For the status bar in the project settings I set: `Status Bar Style - Default`. I don't use anything else for the status bar.

The problem is when the iOS dark mode is enabled my `status bar` goes white. And I need it to stay black. How to fix it?

Also I don't want to turn off iOS dark/light mode supporting in the app. So the **Appearance Light** in the `Info.plist` doesn't quite work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your status bar style to dark content:

[image]

After that add in your info.plist **View controller-based status bar appearance** and set it to **NO**

[image]

**UPDATE**

if you want dark content only in determinate controller add setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate in viewWillAppear and after that override preferredStatusBarStyle:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return .darkContent
    } else {
        return .default
    }
```

**Begin with navigation Controller:**

In your Scene delegate declare your first navigation controller:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstViewController())
    controller.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    window?.rootViewController = controller
}
```

in SecondViewController override the status bar style

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return .darkContent
    } else {
        return .default
    }
}
```

Comment: In some controllers I need to have white color. Because If I use your answer I have this - https://ibb.co/Dfy3Cd0

Comment: I update my answer.... If my answer satisfy your Question, please check it with right answer and upvote...

Comment: You don't need this if statement, but if you want add return .default in else statement

Comment: I need it because app supporting iOS 12. However, if I use iOS 13 support and use your code, the status bar color does not change. I am use breakpoints and check that "preferredStatusBarStyle" not called. I don't know why...

Comment: have you add return.default in else statement? (below //Fallback on earlier version) Take a look in my answer...

Comment: Yes - https://ibb.co/jD1jJ25 Also I truing to change iOS deployment target to 13 and use your code. But in this case it is doesn't  work too.

Comment: have you delete View controller-based status bar appearance in info.plist? I try it and works like a charme, in alternative open new project paste my code and look...

Comment: Yes I create new project. And in `ViewController` status bar works fine. But when I add `NavigationController` and connected it with `ViewController` my status bar have white color again

Comment: I use this for navbar `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`, `self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always`, `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()`

Comment: If you don't solve let me know, I'll look at it better tomorrow

Comment: I trying but nothing... For example in storyboard I have `NavigationController` -> `FirstViewController` -> `SecondViewController`. If I create NavigationController class and use your code I have black status bar color in all app(as I wanted). But if I need to change color to white in `SecondViewController` it doesn't work

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If you don''t try my last update....

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

For each `ViewController` you can set status bar color with simple override method.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        return .darkContent
    } else {
        return .default
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set **View controller-based status bar appearance** to **YES** in your Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine and simple code for each view controller

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .white
}
```

Below, we are using different styles for each ViewController. You can set the status bar color with a simple override method.

1. Dark Content
2. White
3. Black
4. Default
5. Light Content

Don't forget to set the **View controller-based status bar appearance** to YES in your Info.plist.